# Find distance to waypoints? Or waypoint within x miles?

Tags: android, google-maps, positioning, distance

This is more of a theoretical question on how to do it rather then an actual programming question. Target platform is Android, though.

I have a list of waypoints. And I have my current position. I want to know if any of the waypoints are close to me, eg. +/-5 km. I could calculate the distans to each waypoint seperately to find out if it is within the specified radius, but isn't there a better way to do this? Like, are these points included in this area (area beeing a 5km circle around my position) (you can do something like this when working with graphics and click/touch events)?

Any help is appreciated!

/Magnus

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Geo-spatial analysis? There is an open source java project for this.

http://java-source.net/open-source/geospatial

Google of course provides this service as part of pro maps package.

http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/index.html

(Note: I use semantic technology and allegrograph provides a decent geospatial api)